# A combinatorial question: Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $X = \{f:S\rightarrow S | x<y \implies f(x)\leq f(y)\}.$ Find $|X|$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $S = {1,2,3,4}$ and $X = \{f:S\rightarrow S \ | \ x<y \implies f(x)\leq f(y)\}.$ Find $|X|$.

The solution is $\binom{7}{3}$, and the explanation was using stars and bars. I don't see how it could possibly be connected to a stars and bars problem.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: For each $f$ define a function $g$ on $\{1,2,\dots,\color{red}{5}\}$ to be $g(x)= \begin{cases}f(1)& \text{if}~x=1\\ f(x)-f(x-1)& \text{if}~x\in\{2,3,4\}\\ 5& \text{if}~ x=5\end{cases}$.  What do you notice?

Comment: Alternatively, relate the problem to that of counting how many integer lattice paths there are which use only rights and ups.  The highest point in the path in each column corresponds to the value of $f(x)$.